# Encoding / Decoding Caesar cipher Python 3 ASCII

Tags: python

I am learning to code through the introduction to computer science book written by John Zelle. I am stuck on exercise 5.8. I need to somehow modify this solution where the next character after "z" is "a" in order to make it circular. Any help would be great :)

```
def main():
    print("This program can encode and decode Caesar Ciphers") #e.g. if key value is 2 --> word shifted 2 up e.g. a would be c
    #input from user
    inputText = input("Please enter a string of plaintext:").lower()
    inputValue = eval(input("Please enter the value of the key:"))
    inputEorD = input("Please enter e (to encrypt) or d (to decrypt) ")
    #initate empty list
    codedMessage = ""

    #for character in the string
    if inputEorD == "e":
        for ch in inputText:
            codedMessage += chr(ord(ch) + inputValue) #encode hence plus
    elif inputEorD =="d":
            codedMessage += chr(ord(ch) - inputValue) #decode hence minus
    else:
        print("You did not enter E/D! Try again!!")
    print("The text inputed:", inputText,  ".Is:", inputEorD, ".By the key of",inputValue, ".To make the message", codedMessage)

main()
```

Comment: Hint: use the [modulo](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with `.lower()`-case letters, it's fair to know that their ASCII range is [97-122].

A good way to make the shifting circular would be to represent each letter with the range [0-25], which is done by `ord(ch) - 97`, and then add the key, then modulo the result with 26 so it becomes `(ord(ch) - 97 + key)%26`, we'll then have a result in range [0-25], adding 97 will then get it's ASCII code:

```
def main():
    print("This program can encode and decode Caesar Ciphers")
    inputText = input("Please enter a string of plaintext:").lower()
    inputValue = int(input("Please enter the value of the key:")) # use int(), don't eval unless you read more about it
    inputEorD = input("Please enter e (to encrypt) or d (to decrypt) ")
    codedMessage = ""

    if inputEorD == "e":
        for ch in inputText:
            codedMessage += chr((ord(ch) - 97 + inputValue)%26 + 97)
    elif inputEorD =="d":
            codedMessage += chr((ord(ch) - 97 - inputValue)%26 + 97)
    else:
        print("You did not enter E/D! Try again!!")
    print("The text inputed:", inputText,  ".Is:", inputEorD, ".By the key of",inputValue, ".To make the message", codedMessage)

main()
```

Comment: @karan Glad to help :).